# Не распознаются подгружаемые из базы данных символы

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

Есть сайт на словацком языке. Там всякие буквы "с верхом" типа "ä", "č", "ľ". Есть на нем контент, подгружаемый с БД. Но при подгрузке подобные символы не распознаются и заменяются знаком вопроса. Пробовал кодировки "utf8_general_ci", "utf8_slovak_ci", "ascii_general_ci". Ничего не работает, но при этом в phpmyadmin все отображается корректно. Как это исправить?

P. S.: Все это на локальном сервере lamp (последней версии) в linux mint.

[image: Сайт]
[image: Данные]

Comment: Где вы пробовали? Какая кодировка стоит у поля в базе? С какой кодировкой вы подключаетесь?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov , Кодировки пробовал менять у самих полей в БД. Сейчас оставил utf8_general_ci. Не совсем понял, что значит "с какой кодировкой подключаетесь"?

Comment: Какое содержимое файла my.cnf ? В секции `[client]` есть указание `default-character-set`? Если да - посмотрите что указано в нем. Если нет - поставьте в `default-character-set=utf8`, да перезапустите apache. И да, кодировка страницы тоже должна совпадать(в этом случае - utf8)

Comment: А "utf8_general_ci, utf8_slovak_ci, ascii_general_ci" - это не кодировки. Это указание на специфичный набор правил для сравнения символов при поиске в базе(collation).

Comment: После подключения к БД первой командой выполните запрос `SET NAMES utf8`

Comment: У php файла укажите в заголовках кодировку аналогичными командами `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');` в самом начале файла